# Munin server can't connect to node

Tags: centos7, linux-networking, munin

I want to add a new node running CentOS 7 to be monitored by my munin server (CentOS 7), but it cannot connect to it. It connects to my other nodes (also CentOS 7) just fine, and is able to ping the new node in question:

```
[root@australium ~]# ping my-munin-node
PING my-munin-node (132.229.44.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from my-munin-node (132.229.44.220): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.597 ms
[root@australium ~]# ncat 132.229.44.220 4949
Ncat: No route to host.
```

As far as I can tell, my firewall shouldn't be blocking it:

```
[root@my-munin-node ~]# iptables -S | grep 4949
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4949 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
```

Here is the verbose ncat output:

```
[root@australium ~]# ncat -vvvv 132.229.44.220 4949
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /usr/share/ncat/ca-bundle.crt.
NCAT DEBUG: Unable to load trusted CA certificates from /usr/share/ncat/ca-bundle.crt: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
libnsock nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #1)
libnsock msevent_new(): msevent_new (IOD #1) (EID #8)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 132.229.44.220:4949 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsp_add_event(): NSE #8: Adding event
libnsock nsock_loop(): nsock_loop() started (no timeout). 1 events pending
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT ERROR [No route to host (113)] for EID 8 [132.229.44.220:4949]
Ncat: No route to host.
```

Any potential solutions or pointers would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the IP was still blocked from my client. I have not been able to find out how to view or confirm this, but explicitly adding the ip of my munin server has fixed the issue:

```
[root@my-munin-node ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-source=132.229.44.132
You're performing an operation over default zone ('public'),
but your connections/interfaces are in zone 'internal,external' (see --get-active-zones)
You most likely need to use --zone=internal option.

success
[root@my-munin-node ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-source=132.229.44.132
Error: ZONE_CONFLICT: 132.229.44.132
[root@my-munin-node ~]# systemctl restart firewalld
```